# Connect 2 external monitors to LenovoY580 at Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: nvidia, graphics, multiple-monitors, lenovo

I have LenovoY580 laptop with Intel HD 4000 Graphics + nvidia GEFORCE GTX 660M.
I have been trying to connect one external monitor via VGA and another (a TV) by HDMI (to work on three screens - including laptop screen). Both monitors work fine when connected separately. If I try them simultaneusly I get errors:

> could not set the configuration for CRTC 102
>   GDBus.Error:org.gtk.GDBus.UnmappedGError.Quark._gnome_2drr_2derror_2dquark.Code2:
>   could not set the configuration for CRTC 102

I guess it is the problem of more than 2 screens using Intel graphic card.
I would like to ask how to set my nvidia card to aid me with displays on Ubuntu 14.04 ?

EDIT:
I got Nvidia X Server Settings but it only detects "Screen 0"...It must be the drivers...
I get the "No Scanout" message - i cannot detect others screens no matter what drivers I use